# Error while building my catkin during the installation of VREP Plugin

Tags: ros, plugin, vrep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After building my file using CMkae, all the packages went through the process but one and here is the error :

```
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vrep_ros_bridge/quadrotor_tk_handler)
```

CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "telekyb_msgs" with
any of the following names:

```
telekyb_msgsConfig.cmake
telekyb_msgs-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "telekyb_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"telekyb_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"telekyb_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
vrep_ros_bridge/quadrotor_tk_handler/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Could not find the required component 'telekyb_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "telekyb_msgs" with
any of the following names:

```
telekyb_msgsConfig.cmake
telekyb_msgs-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "telekyb_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"telekyb_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"telekyb_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
vrep_ros_bridge/quadrotor_tk_handler/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/amel/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/amel/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Erreur 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Thanks & Best Regards

Space

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242526/error-while-building-my-catkin-during-the-installation-of-vrep-plugin/) by [Space](https://answers.ros.org/users/27006/space/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TeleKyb seems to be a framework to control quadrotor UAVs. According to the [vrep_ros_bridge](https://github.com/lagadic/vrep_ros_bridge) git site:

> It is possible that you will not need all the sub-plugins provided by the vrep_ros_bridge. A common case is the one in which you do not need to use the TeleKyb framework (if you do not know what TeleKyb is, it is likely that you will not need it). To ignore this sub-plugin you need to add the file CATKIN_IGNORE in the sub-plugin folder that you do not need (as it is done in quadrotor_tk_handler).

To do this, go to the sub-plugin directory called quadrotor_tk_handler and add the CATKIN_IGNORE file in it like this :

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/vrep_ros_bridge/quadrotor_tk_handler
touch CATKIN_IGNORE
```

You can look up the rest of the instructions the site. I was able to install it without any problems.
Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [pridanks](https://answers.ros.org/users/29100/pridanks/) with karma: 176 on 2017-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0